# Why the display method of the iOS CALayer subclass not called

Tags: ios

The demo code：

```
@interface MyLayer : CALayer
@end

@implementation MyLayer

- (void)display {
    NSLog(@"display hello");
    [super display];
}


@end

@interface MyView : UIView<CALayerDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyView

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [MyLayer class];
}

@end


@interface MyViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyViewController

...

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
...

@end
```

As I understand: display func must be called at least once when CALayer is displayed, but why MyLayer display method is not called?

If make a change and only add the drawRect: method to MyView, MyLayer's display method will be called.

```
@implementation MyView

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [MyLayer class];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawRect");
}

@end
```

I understand the internal logic of the display method, but I do not understand the reason why the display method is not called. Please help me